# If someone files a claim for short term disability for maternity leave, would future premiums be adversely affected?

Tags: united-states, insurance, california, maternity-leave

If filing a claim for maternity leave does not increase the premiums required in the future, is it because the insurance company is not allowed to use the information, because it is not predictive, or for some other reason?

Is the answer different if she files for both state disability and private vs just state disability?

Comment: Where is the claim being filed?  Obviously the CA disability program is a payroll tax.  There are employer programs that can be used, but there is a wide variety of those from full voluntary individual coverage and participation in a group STD program but the answers are pretty different between the kind of coverage in place.

Comment: @quid, I would like to better understand the determining factors when the future application is for private individual insurance.  Does the answer depend on the state of today's potential claim or on the state at the time of the future potential application?  Does it matter whether today's claim is only for government and/or group disability?  Or is the answer the same regardless of the type of insurance used today?

Comment: Sure, prior disabilities could impact future underwriting outcomes for individual disability coverage, but not it would be based on medical conditions.  This wouldn't matter in group contracts or CA state disability which is a payroll tax because those programs don't know the specific covered people.  Experience/claims could matter in employer sponsored individual coverage or just individually procured coverage.  But again, the condition matters because pregnancy is a common exclusion for those.  But this question would require a small textbook to answer broadly.

Comment: @quid, is there a textbook you recommend?

Comment: I don't know of one in particular. The condition leading to the disability will matter for future underwriting, whether or not you collected against an insurer is irrelevant, the element that matters is your medical history.  Individual disability insurance is a contract between you and the insurer which binds the insurer to the risk as long as you keep paying and it is hard for the insurer to cancel or change the contract after it's issued in states like CA.  It's not like auto or other property insurance where things change and renew frequently.